# Create Rectangle class that is almost identical to the Circle class. Use Rect as the class name. JAVA, i think my error is coming from public boolean

Tags: java, polymorphism

Create a Rectangle class that is almost identical to the Circle class.  Use Rect as the class name.  The easiest way to write this class will be to copy all the code from Circle.java into Rect.java, then change the class name, instance variables, and statements. My rect code only opens a blank window when I use the shapemover. Please help me identify what I am doing wrong.

Here's the circle class code:

```
    package lab08;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Color;

    /**
     * Circle objects represent a circle shape
     * drawn to the screen at a particular position
     * with some size and color.
     *
     * @author Peter Jensen, Donat Mouele
     * @version Fall 2022
     */
    public class Circle extends Shape

    {
        // Instance variables.

        private int x, y;
        private Color color;
        private int radius;

        /**
         * Constructor - initializes the position, diameter, and
         * color of this circle object.
         *
         * @param x
         *         the x coordinate of this object's position
         *
         * @param y
         *         the x coordinate of this object's position
         *
         * @param diameter
         *              the diameter of this circle
         *
         * @param color
         *             the color of this circle
         */
        public Circle (int x, int y, int diameter, Color color)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.color = color;
            this.radius = diameter / 2;
        }

        /**
         * Changes the position of this shape by
         * the specified amount.  Note that this does
         * not set the position absolutely, the deltas
         * specify how far to move the shape from its
         * current position.
         *
         * @param deltaX
         *              how far to move the shape horizontally
         *
         * @param deltaY
         *              how far to move the shape vertically
         */
        public void move (int deltaX, int deltaY)
        {
            x = x + deltaX;
            y = y + deltaY;
        }

        /**
         * Draws the circle at it's current position and color
         * to the specified graphics object.
         *
         * @param g
         *         the graphics object (where to draw to)
         */
        public void draw (Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor (color);
            g.fillOval (x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        }  
        
        /**
         * Returns true if the coordinates are within the circle.
         *
         * @param targetX
         *               an x coordinate
         *
         * @param targetY
         *               a y coordinate
         *
         * @return
         *        true if the coordinates are within the shape
         */
        public boolean isInside (int targetX, int targetY)
        {
            int cx = x + radius;  // Calculate the center point
            int cy = y + radius;
            
            int deltaX = cx - targetX;  // Calculate the deltas to the click
            int deltaY = cy - targetY;
            
            // Make sure the distance from the click to the center is less
            //   than the radius.  (Notice how I avoid a square root.)
            
            return (deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY) <= radius * radius;
        }
    }
```

Here's the Rectangle Class Code that I have

```
    package lab08;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Color;

    /**
     * Circle objects represent a circle shape
     * drawn to the screen at a particular position
     * with some size and color.
     *
     * @author Peter Jensen, Donat Mouele
     * @version Fall 2022
     */
    public class Rect extends Shape
    {
        // Instance variables.

        private int x, y;
        private Color color;
        private int height;
        private int width;

        /**
         * Constructor - initializes the position, diameter, and
         * color of this circle object.
         *
         * @param x
         *         the x coordinate of this object's position
         *
         * @param y
         *         the x coordinate of this object's position
         *
         * @param diameter
         *              the diameter of this circle
         *
         * @param color
         *             the color of this circle
         */
        public Rect (int x, int y, int perimeter, Color color)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.color = color;
            this.height = perimeter / 2 - width;
            this.width = perimeter/2-height;
        }

        /**
         * Changes the position of this shape by
         * the specified amount.  Note that this does
         * not set the position absolutely, the deltas
         * specify how far to move the shape from its
         * current position.
         *
         * @param deltaX
         *              how far to move the shape horizontally
         *
         * @param deltaY
         *              how far to move the shape vertically
         */
        public void move (int deltaX, int deltaY)
        {
            x = x + deltaX;
            y = y + deltaY;
        }

        /**
         * Draws the circle at it's current position and color
         * to the specified graphics object.
         *
         * @param g
         *         the graphics object (where to draw to)
         */
        public void draw (Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor (color);
            g.fillOval (x, y, width, height);
        }  
        
        /**
         * Returns true if the coordinates are within the circle.
         *
         * @param targetX
         *               an x coordinate
         *
         * @param targetY
         *               a y coordinate
         *
         * @return
         *        true if the coordinates are within the shape
         */
        public boolean isInside (int targetX, int targetY)
        {
            int cx = x + width;  // Calculate the center point
            int cy = y + height;
            
            int deltaX = cx - targetX;  // Calculate the deltas to the click
            int deltaY = cy - targetY;
            
            return     targetX >= x &&
                       targetX < x + width &&
                       targetY >= y &&
                       targetY < y + height;
        }
    }
```

Here's the shape mover

```
package lab08;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * This class represents and application/JPanel that
 * draws a few shapes for the user and allows the
 * user to drag the shapes around with the mouse.
 *
 * @author Peter Jensen
 * @version Fall 2022
 */
public class ShapeMover extends JPanel implements MouseListener,
                                                  MouseMotionListener,
                                                  Runnable
{
    // Instance variables.
    
    Rect[] shapes;

    int lastX, lastY;
        Rect current;

    /**
     * Initialize this (our JPanel).  Create the shapes, and
     * register this object as a listener to mouse events
     * produced by this object.
     */
    public ShapeMover ()
    {
        // Make the shapes.
        
        shapes = new Rect[]
            {
               new Rect    (130,  40,  60, Color.RED),
               new Rect   (230,  40,  20, Color.BLUE),
               new Rect    (330,  40,  80, Color.GREEN.darker()),
               new Rect    (130, 140, 100, new Color (0.8f, 0.6f, 0.2f)),
               new Rect    ( 30, 140,  40, Color.YELLOW)
            };
    
        // Set the size of this panel.
        
        Dimension d = new Dimension (600, 600);
        this.setMinimumSize(d);
        this.setPreferredSize(d);
        this.setMaximumSize(d);
        
        // Register this object as a listener to its own events.
        
        this.addMouseListener (this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener (this);
    }

    /**
     * Draws the shapes at their current locations
     * and colors.
     *
     * @param g
     *         the Graphics object to draw to
     */
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        // Clear the background to a nice light blue color.
        
        g.setColor(new Color (0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        
        // Draw all of the shapes.
        
        for (Rect s : shapes)
            s.draw(g);
    }

    /**
     * This method is part of the MouseListener interface.
     * Because we registered this application object as a listener
     * to its own mouse events, this method will be automatically
     * called whenever the mouse button is pressed down.
     *
     * In this method, we determine if the mouse click occurred
     * in any of our shapes.  If so, we record that shape object
     * as the current shape.  This has the effect of selecting
     * a shape to drag around.
     *
     * @param e
     *         the mouse event
     */
    public void mousePressed  (MouseEvent e) 
    {
        // Get the location of the mouse click within this window.
        
        int x = e.getX (); 
        int y = e.getY ();
    
        // Save it for later use.
        
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
    
        // Determine if the mouse click is within any shape.
        //   If so, save the shape as the current shape.
    
        for (Rect s : shapes)
            if (s.isInside (x, y))
                current = s;
    }
    
    /**
     * This method is part of the MouseListener interface.
     * Because we registered this applet object as a listener
     * to its own mouse events, this method will be automatically
     * called whenever the mouse button is let down.
     *
     * In this method, we mark the current shape as null.  This
     * has the effect of dropping whatever shape we are dragging
     * around.
     *
     * @param e
     *         the mouse event
     */
    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e) 
    {
        current = null;
    }
    
    /**
     * This method is part of the MouseMotionListener interface.
     * Because we registered this applet object as a listener
     * to its own mouse events, this method will be automatically
     * called whenever the mouse is moved with the button pressed down.
     *
     * In this method, we adjust the position of the shape the user
     * is dragging around.
     *
     * @param e
     *         the mouse event
     */
    public void mouseDragged  (MouseEvent e) 
    {
        // Compute how far the mouse moved since the last event.
        
        int x = e.getX (); 
        int y = e.getY ();
        
        int deltaX = x - lastX;
        int deltaY = y - lastY;
    
        // Save the current mouse position.
        
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
    
        // If the user is dragging around a shape, move it by
        //   the same amount that the mouse moved.
        
        if (current != null)
        {
            current.move (deltaX, deltaY); 
            repaint ();
        }
    }

    // Unused event methods (required by the interfaces).

    public void mouseClicked  (MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseEntered  (MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseExited   (MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseMoved    (MouseEvent e) { }
    
    /* Above this point are the methods and variables that we use in the JPanel */
    /* Below this point are the methods and variables that launch the application */
    
    /* I violated separation of concerns.  The JPanel and Application classes
     * are merged, and 'main' is below.  This works for simple code (like this
     * lab), but it is not a good idea for larger projects.
     */
    
    /**
     * The application entry point.
     * 
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // Main runs in the 'main' execution thread, and the GUI
        //   needs to be built by the GUI execution thread.
        //   Ask the GUI thread to run our 'run' method (at some
        //   later time).
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ShapeMover());

        // Done.  Let the main thread of execution finish.  All the
        //   remaining work will be done by the GUI thread.
    }
    
    /**
     * Builds the GUI for this application.  This method must
     * only be called/executed by the GUI thread. 
     */
    public void run ()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Shape Mover 2021");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        // 'this' is our Runnable object, but it is also our JPanel.
        
        f.setContentPane(this); 
        
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  // Centers window
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing at a quick glance - the classes extending `Shape` miss `@Override` annotations for methods, such as `draw`, `move` etc.

Comment: You don't seem to create any `Shape`s. Also, `move()` should be in the base class, and `Rect::isInside()` doesn't actually calculate the centre point, and doesn't need to anyway.